# Make the user press enter just once every time in C

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    char foo;
    scanf("%c", &foo);
    printf("%c\n", foo);

    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

If the user inputs anything, the `getchar()` is "ignored", but when just enter is pressed, the `getchar()` asks for input. A possible solution to this is to put as second `getchar()`, but the user have to press enter two times if the first input is empty, also if there is a buffer in the first input it also gets ignored. What I want is to have the user press enter just once, regardless of the user input. I've read about `fflush(stdin)` but it didn't work for me. So basically, is there a way to clear the input buffer before the `getchar()` in order for it to work?

Comment: No, getchar() is not "ignored".  If there are 2 characters on the input stream, then it returns immediately.  If there is only one character on the input stream, it is consumed by `scanf` and `getchar` blocks until another character is available or the input stream is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interactive program, where you need more control over the input, consider using `fgets` to read lines, and `sscanf` to parse. This will let the code decide when the 'flush' remaining characters on the line

```
main(...)
{
    char buff[200] ;
    if ( !fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) ) {
        // Error
    } ;
    char foo ;
    sscanf(buff, "%c", &foo) ;

    // next fgets (and getchar) will force reading a line!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By not calling the **getchar();** you only need to press enter once

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    char foo;
    scanf("%c", &foo);
    printf("%c\n", foo);

    return 0;
 }
```